# Uber sandbox API does not allow no_drivers_available and rider_canceled status changes on a ride

Tags: uber-api

I booked a ride, moved it to ACCEPTED state, and tried to cancel it by updating the ride status to rider_canceled. In both cases, I get message stating that it are not valid product status.

Also, after requesting a ride, I tried moving to no_drivers_available, got the same error.

Any clues why ?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any issues updating the status to "driver_canceled". If that's still a problem for you, can you post some example code?

For "rider_canceled", you need to make a DELETE request for that request id. From https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox#section-other-request-statuses:

> rider_canceled -  The Request canceled by rider. Issue a DELETE command to give a Request this status

Comment: To receive a no_drivers_available error you first have to issue a [PUT /v1/sandbox/products/{product_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox#section-product-types) request using the product_id, **before** you make the actual ride request.